# Execution failed for task app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac, after updating the android studio from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-debug

**EDIT :** Initially it looked insurmountable and I have overlooked. The actual problem is a facile victory. What really happened is somehow, unintentionally I've created (or) it has created `fragment_feed.xml(v14)` file along with original `fragment_feed.xml` file after upgrading to 3.1.0. But, the Button Id's were not present in `(v14)fragment_feed.xml` which were actually present in original `fragment_feed.xml` file anb I have declared them in my `FeedFragment.java` file but `FeedFragment.java` is considering only `(v14)fragment_feed.xml` while compiling. I have added button Id's in the `(v14)fragment_feed.xml` file. Then it worked absolutely fine.

So, check if there are any `v14` kinda `xml` files existing and check if there is anything missing that's been declared in `.java` file.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: 
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute
(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute
(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.
delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.
execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute
(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute
(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute
(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
 at 
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.
 IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute
 (IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.
IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute
(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
at 
org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation
(JavaCompile.java:207)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:133)
at 
com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile
(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
 .java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at 
org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute
(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute
(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute
(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run
(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor
$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute
(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor
$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute
(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute
(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run
(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 32 more
```

This is the stacktrace. I have tried everything, nothing worked. I even downloaded new Android studio and imported the project, still it is showing the same error. From the above stacktrace, you can look from caused by: line.

[image: Build errors]

[image: error description]

Please help me. It is not accepting any new code. old code is working fine. Old code means, the code existed before updating the android studio. I have been facing this issue from 3 days.This error occurred after migrating to 3.1.0 from 3.0.1.

Project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.authent.authentication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle wrapper propertice

```
#Thu Mar 29 16:24:24 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4- 
all.zip
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle-wrapper.properties file?

Comment: '#Thu Mar 29 16:24:24 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'

Comment: post all of your gradle files ..edit the question and post !!

Comment: I have posted everything... @SantanuSur

Comment: add  buildToolsVersion '27.0.0' below compileSdkVersion

Comment: But, it was deprecated...

Comment: What is deprecated?

Comment: buildToolsVersion in App level gradle in newer versions I think. Okay, anyway I will add and Tell you what.

Comment: Did not work.. same error

Comment: `maven { url "https://maven.google.com"        }` try adding it to the topmost buildscript

Comment: top most buildscript means..??

Answer (score 0):

Initially it looked insurmountable and I have overlooked. The actual problem is a facile victory. What really happened is somehow, unintentionally I've created (or) it has created `fragment_feed.xml(v14)` file along with original `fragment_feed.xml` file after upgrading to 3.1.0. But, the Button Id's were not present in `(v14)fragment_feed.xml` which were actually present in original `fragment_feed.xml` file anb I have declared them in my `FeedFragment.java` file but `FeedFragment.java` is considering only `(v14)fragment_feed.xml` while compiling. I have added button Id's in the `(v14)fragment_feed.xml` file. Then it worked absolutely fine.

So, check if there are any `v14` kinda `xml` files existing and check if there is anything missing that's been declared in `.java` file.